# Datalist in c# desktop app

Tags: c#

I want to make a dataset e.g. I'm making a replica of Instagram and I want to display pictures, name, likes, comments from same table.
I could've used datalist in asp.net but what's the replacement in c# desktop app?

Comment: Is it a windows forms application?

Comment: What research up my did for this? Did you go thru the controls available in the toolbox in visual studio?

Comment: You need to specify what platform you are using for your desktop application - e.g. WinForms or WPF

Comment: it is windows forms application.

Comment: there's data repeater control but it not work like that smh.

Answer (score 0):

You may use ADO.Net code in asp.net application and windows application there is not much difference in that. In fact you may write a class library and re-use the same code.

Comment: The question is not about accessing the data - it is about how to display the data when the DataList control is not available in a desktop application.

Comment: your answer is far not related to the question. better you edit or delete it.